# Apostrofo dentro de echo

Tags: php, sql

bom estou tentando colocar no slide as imagens porem o apostrofo esta quebrando , onde é o erro? editado abaixo o resumo apos os testes que fiz mesmo usando as \ .

```
meu codigo atual
echo "<div class='fill' style='background-image:url(\'img/{$exibe[0]->idnoticia}/{$exibe[0]->imagem}\');'></div>";


codigo de exemplo do bootstrap
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>


codigo exibido pelo browser
<div class="item active"><div class="fill" style="background-image:url(\" img="" 22="" 1429033737_screenshot_11.jpg\');'=""></div>
```

realmente nao estou entendendo o que se passa se alguem puder dar uma luz ta valendo
assim so lembrando que desta maneira funciona, porem gostaria de saber qual o erro acima

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/<?php echo "{$exibe[0]->idnoticia}/{$exibe[0]->imagem}"; ?>');"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é que você esta usando apostrofo(') para os atributos da sua div e também para coisas dentro do atributo, e escapes sem necessidade, nisso o browser tenta interpretar algo do seu output e entende essa bagunça que você postou.

Seu output atual deve estar sendo algo assim:

```
<div class='fill' style='background-image:url(\'img/22/1429033737_screenshot_11.jpg\');'>
```

Como esse html que você gerou é invalido, o browser tenta interpretar e fica essa sopa que você postou no terceiro exemplo.

acho que isso resolve o seu problema:

```
<?php
echo "<div class=\"fill\" style=\"background-image:url('img/{$exibe[0]->idnoticia}/{$exibe[0]->imagem}')\"></div>";
```

Caso você não queria se perder nos escapes, você pode usar a sintaxe heredoc

exemplo:

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/{$exibe[0]->idnoticia}/{$exibe[0]->imagem}')"></div>
HTML;
```

Comment: desconhecia essa sintaxe heredoc, testei aqui e funcionou, quanto a sua solucao para o meu problema tambem ja havia tentado tambem nao funcionou

Comment: Vou testar mais tarde, deve haver algum errinho besta.

Comment: Acho que resolvi.

Comment: pode alterar o codigo ou postar aki nos comentarios o que fez?

Comment: Alterei na resposta,.

Comment: segue exemplo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1256f8257f5ba5bc574817d95b86f8b0156b8b87